# Oracle Blob to XLS worksheet

Tags: java, excel, oracle11g, apache-poi, ibatis

Edit: Solved.  I circumvented the ibatis/ApachePOI by writing a jdbc connector to the database, getting the blob, and dumping it to a file.  Someday, I'd like to know exactly why it was screwing up - but today I'm happy to have this behind me.

Summary: I'm getting Oracle blobs and using Apache POI to reconstitute Excel binaries to pass through a SOAP service layer.  The .Net client is writing these to .xls files just fine, but has corrupt files when writing to a UNIX directory.

Detail:
I have Excel blobs stored in an oracle table.  These blobs are written using iBatis, and pulled using this (truncated) result map.

```
<resultMap id="report" class="Report">      
  <result column="content" property ="content" typeHandler="BlobByteArrayTypeHandler"/>
```

The excel reports are generated using Apache.POI by our Java services.  At the moment, our Client (.net) queries the service for a byte array, which is written to a Windows machine without error - just dumping the bytes to a file.

These excel files are just fine.

The problem I'm having is that we have a new requirement that we should be writing these files out to a UNIX file system, for further processing.

All attempts at this have failed.  Here are some code samples:

```
private void writeReportDumpBytes(Report report) {
    File file = new File("report.xls");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream.write(report.getContent());
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

private void writeReportWithEncoding(Report report, String encoding) {
    File file = new File("Report.xls");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, encoding);         
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        String reportBytes = new String(report.getContent());
        out.write(reportBytes.toCharArray());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
}

public void writeReportHssfPoifileSystem(Report report) {
    try {
        InputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(report.getContent());
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(byteStream);
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);           
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Report.xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private void writeReportApacheIO(Report report) {
    File file = new File("Report.xls");
    try {           
        logReportBytes(report, "Apache IO");            
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, report.getContent());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Caught IOException", e);
    }               
}
```

In order to diagnose this, I have tried grabbing the blob from Oracle, and saving it to a file.  In a bare-bones jar executable, I have been able to read the bytes from this file, and rewrite it using the above methods on our UNIX box - and they all work.

However, from our code, the excel files are all corrupt, or missing header information from Apache.POI.  Opening the corrupt/bad binaries in a text editor shows a repeating pattern of 64 bytes.  It is not a valid xls binary.

Something is going sideways.  The blob is a valid xls binary, and we are just getting the bytes (using the iBatis above) and passing them back through a HSSFWorkbook object, and trying to write using the methods as I've shown them.

```
    /**
 * Return the byte array based on the workbook.
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public byte[] getContent() throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    this.workBook.write(bos);   
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

The specific error I'm getting when using Apache POI is:

```
java.io.IOException: block[ 0 ] already removed
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockListImpl.remove(BlockListImpl.java:97)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockAllocationTableReader.fetchBlocks(BlockAllocationTableReader.java:190)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockListImpl.fetchBlocks(BlockListImpl.java:130)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.PropertyTable.<init>(PropertyTable.java:79)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:171)
```

Comment: Excel files are binary data. You appear to be using Writers and Encodings, which should only be used with Plain Text. Using them with binary data breaks things! What happens if you zap all the Writers and just work with bytes/streams?

Comment: My first example uses a FileOutputStream only to write, very similar to the working .Net code, but not working in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jdbc call directly to the DB ignoring all the nonsense of ibatis and apache poi.  Worked just fine using a variety of disk write methods.